# How to make the network uninterrupted when the system is locked on elementary os

Tags: networking

Sometimes, I need to lock the elementary os and let some jobs can still work. But I found when I lock the elementary os for a while (> 2h), the network will interrupt. I need the network uninterrupted when the system is locked but I don't know how to do. is there any method?

Comment: Is it a new installation of elementary OS

Answer (score 1):

Please go to the *System Settings* and select *Power*. After that please change the option for "Turn of the display when inactive for" to *Never*. Please be sure to do this for both *On Battery* and *Plugged In*.

Also you might want to check the options for closing lid cause if they are set to suspend or something like that, closing lid can cause you problem too.

Comment: I get a useful answer from  [here](https://superuser.com/a/1315412)

Comment: @huangjs please add the answer here as an answer so others facing similar problem feel it easier to solve their problem.